# Trying to convert a timestamp to a datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a timestamp to a datetime to do some date comparisons but I cant seem to get it to work.

```
date = pd.to_datetime(df.at[i,"Date"])
```

however when I do date comparisons using the > and < operators its not always working. From what I have researched dates need to be set to datetime objects not timestamps.

but when i check the type of my `date` variable it still shows as being a timestamp.

```
print(type(date))

<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

How can I convert this to a datetime object/variable ?

Comment: Why was this question closed? the posted link doesnt solve my problem!

Comment: Why doesn't it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Timestamp.to_pydatetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime.html#pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime)

```py
$ type(date.to_pydatetime())

<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```